# Error: Unable to initialize main class [in Eclipse]

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to run my Java program in Eclipse, with the following code:

```
public class TextFileIndex/* TODO Implement the SimpleIndex interface for Path locations */ {

    public void add(E location, String word) {
        
    }
    
    
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    public int size(E location) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    public boolean contains(E location) {
        return false;
    }
    
    
    public boolean contains(E location, String word) {
        return false;
    }
    
    
    public Collection<E> get(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented.");
    }
    
    
    public Collection<String> get(E location){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented.");
    }

    
    
    // TODO Modify this class as necessary.

    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        
    }
}
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class TextFileIndex
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: E
```

My other projects have worked fine, and I have downloaded/ rebuilt the project to be sure. What's going on?

Comment: You don't have a constuctor?

Answer (score 0):

Add `<E>` to your class

```
public class TextFileIndex<E>
```

Read the doc [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Comment: Seems to have removed the error. Do you know why I needed the E?

Comment: Well <E> denotes the type parameter of the class it could be a String,Integer etc , so if you say TextFileIndex<String> textFileIndex = new TextFileIndex<>(); the methods that this class has E transforms to String so example in the add method now E acts like String  textFileIndex.add("Location","word");